# ubercart zip/postal code reformatting in views using php

Tags: theming, 6, ubercart

Is it possible to rewrite in views (possibly with php field) ubercart's customers zip numnber? The original format is "12345". I need to put a empty space after 3rd digit like "123 45". Can anybody help me with php code? 
I put

```
  chunk_split($data->delivery_postal_code, 3, ' ');
```

inside custom php field inside value field but views output empty field.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

for anybody interested - this is the working code

```
 return chunk_split($data->uc_orders_delivery_postal_code, 3, ' ');
```